# std::vector preallocation (size n, capacity n + 2)

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector, allocation

My use-case is the following:
A vector of size `n` read from a binary file.

Among other variants (iostreams, in my case custom code doing decompression), I can do something with semantics like this:

```
vector<myElem> v;
v.resize(n); // from my understanding v now has size n and capacity n
fread(v.data(), sizeof(myElem), n, myFile);
```

However, later I will have to (repeatedly) add and remove two elements to such a vector. (While this sounds pretty stupid, it can have positive effects to add sentinel values to lists so that intersections of sorted lists do not have to add comparisons for bound-checking).

For that, I would love to prealloacte a vector with size `n` and capacity `n + 2`.
I think I could do something like:

```
vector<myElem> v;
v.resize(n + 2); // from my understanding v now has size n + 2 and capacity n + 2 
v.pop_back();
v.pop_back(); // v now has size n and most probably still has capacity 2 (unless n is pretty small)
fread(v.data(), sizeof(myElem), n, myFile);
```

Obviously, this is neither pretty nor guaranteed to behave as I would liek it to. In practice, I think it really should behave that way for big `n` and if small `n` should ever occur, a reallocation doesn't matter.

Still, it would be great to hear if there are better ways.

edit:

I am unsure how I can make use of `reserve` in my case. If I reserve a capacity of `n + 2`, the vector still has size `0`. If I resize to `n`, i also change the capacity.

If I resize first and then reserv, I allocate memory two times and copy the whole vector in the process.

Comment: If only there were a [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to set the capacity.

Comment: @MikeSeymour thanks for pointing it out. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Not nice Mike.  This is a Q&A site. Not all of us read the entire STL documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `v.reserve(n + 2)` to change the `vector`'s capacity without altering its size. Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) to better understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, can you refer to my latest edit, please?
A reserve before the resize would be reverted and a reserve afterwards would lead to a second allocation, as far as i understand

Comment: @b.buchhold why do you think so? A resize does not necesarily change the capacity. Capacity will only change if more elements are requested. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/)

Comment: Alright thanks. I think i misunderstood the reference I had a look at.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of capacity isn't quote correct:

```
v.resize(n); // from my understanding v now has size n and capacity n
```

`v` has size `n`, yes, but all you can say about the capacity is that it is `>= n`. It could be `n`, it could be `n + 1`, it could be `3 * n`. Similarly:

```
v.resize(n + 2); // from my understanding v now has size n + 2 and capacity n + 2 
v.pop_back();
v.pop_back(); // v now has size n and most probably still has capacity 2 (unless n is pretty small)
```

At this point, what we can say with certainty is `v.size() == n && v.capacity() >= n + 2`.

If what you want to do is

> I would love to prealloacte a vector with size n and capacity n + 2

then that's simply:

```
v.reserve(n + 2); // capacity >= n+2, size == 0
v.resize(n);      // capacity >= n+2, size == n
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
v.reserve(n+2);
v.resize(n);
```

This is *guaranteed* to give you a vector with a size of `n` and a capacity of at least `n+2`:

> **23.3.7.3 vector capacity**
>
> void reserve(size_type n)
>
> ...No reallocation shall take place during insertions that happen after a call to reserve()
>   until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of capacity().
>
> void resize(size_type n)
>
> ...If `size() < sz` appaends `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence

So resize to a larger than current size is equivalent to inserting elements, and after a reserve, no insertion operation can reallocate memory until its size would exceed the reserved capacity...